# Need a Simple Line Gradient Generator

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

I need to write or find an application that will generate jpg line gradients, like the one below.
[image: line gradient]

This application would probably be based on HTML5 or CSS3, which already have linear gradient generating commands, and would let the user chose the line width, line length, the colors and color positions, and will then generate a jpg that can be saved to a directory.  The application could be online or standalone.

Does anyone know of a application like this, or have some good ideas for writing one? Something in jQuery would be great!

Thanks

Comment: html & css that saves jpg on disc . are you for real ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a gradient stroke on canvas that can be saved as an image.**

[image]

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // create a linear gradient
    var g=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,50,canvas.width,50);
    g.addColorStop(0,"brown");
    g.addColorStop(.33,"orange");
    g.addColorStop(.66,"orange");
    g.addColorStop(1.00,"brown");

    // stroke a gradient line on a black background
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,50);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,50);
    ctx.strokeStyle=g;
    ctx.stroke();

    // let the user right-click save an image of the canvas
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var html="<p>Right-click on image below and Save-Picture-As</p>";
        html+="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='from canvas'/>";  // or canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
        var tab=window.open();
        tab.document.write(html);
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="save">save</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=100></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you.